# Why does loss continue decreasing but performance keep unchanged?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I am using bert-lstm-crf model, with bert model from https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/ and lstm crf models are written by myself.

After training bert-lstm-crf model for 25 epochs, the performance on training set, dev set and test set keep unchanged but the loss continue decreasing. Where should I make a change?

Here is performance:

25th epoch:

```
tensor(10267.6279, device='cuda:0')
(0.42706720346856614, 0.4595134955014995, 0.4426966292134832)
(0.43147208121827413, 0.4271356783919598, 0.42929292929292934)
(0.4460093896713615, 0.4668304668304668, 0.4561824729891957)
```

26th epoch:

```
tensor(10219.3398, device='cuda:0')
(0.44544364508393286, 0.4951682772409197, 0.46899163642101943)
(0.4469135802469136, 0.4547738693467337, 0.45080946450809467)
(0.45871559633027525, 0.4914004914004914, 0.4744958481613286)
```

27th epoch:

```
tensor(10169.0742, device='cuda:0')
(0.44544364508393286, 0.4951682772409197, 0.46899163642101943)
(0.4469135802469136, 0.4547738693467337, 0.45080946450809467)
(0.45871559633027525, 0.4914004914004914, 0.4744958481613286)
```

more epochs:
lower loss with same performance:

```
(0.44544364508393286, 0.4951682772409197, 0.46899163642101943)
(0.4469135802469136, 0.4547738693467337, 0.45080946450809467)
(0.45871559633027525, 0.4914004914004914, 0.4744958481613286)
```

It is really a weird problem, I have no idea how to handle this. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Here is related code:

```
  for epoch in tqdm(range(200)):

  {loss = train_one_epoch(dataloader=source_train_dataloader,
  model=model, optimizer=optimizer)

  train_perf = test_one_epoch(dataloader=source_train_dataloader_for_test,
  model=model)

  dev_perf = test_one_epoch(dataloader=source_dev_dataloader, model=model)

  test_perf = test_one_epoch(dataloader=source_test_dataloader, 
  model=model)

  base_result_loc = "bert_char_ps/bert_char_result"

  # store performance result

  add_model_result(
    base_result_loc,
    epoch,
    loss,
    train_perf,
    dev_perf,
    test_perf)
  }
```

The performance should change with loss, but now it does not

Comment: could you provide some code of the additional lines of CRF LSTM? I trained this BERT last month but there was no problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified this PyTorch [implementation](https://github.com/kamalkraj/BERT-NER) of BERT-NER model and added CRF. I have the following class which works fine in my case.

```
class BertWithCRF(BertPreTrainedModel):

    def __init__(self, config, labels, dropout=0.1):
        super(BertWithCRF, self).__init__(config)
        self.tagset_size = len(labels)
        self.tag_to_ix = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(labels)}
        self.bert = BertModel(config)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, self.tagset_size)
        self.apply(self.init_bert_weights)
        self.transitions = nn.Parameter(
            torch.zeros(self.tagset_size, self.tagset_size))
        self.transitions.data[self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG], :] = -10000
        self.transitions.data[:, self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]] = -10000

    def _batch_forward_alg(self, feats, mask):
        assert mask is not None
        # calculate in log domain
        # feats is batch_size * len(sentence) * tagset_size
        # initialize alpha with a Tensor with values all equal to -10000.
        score = torch.Tensor(feats.size(0), self.tagset_size).fill_(-10000.)
        score[:, self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]] = 0.
        if feats.is_cuda:
            score = score.cuda()
        mask = mask.float()
        trans = self.transitions.unsqueeze(0)  # [1, C, C]
        for t in range(feats.size(1)):  # recursion through the sequence
            mask_t = mask[:, t].unsqueeze(1)
            emit_t = feats[:, t].unsqueeze(2)  # [B, C, 1]
            score_t = score.unsqueeze(1) + emit_t + trans  # [B, 1, C] -> [B, C, C]
            score_t = batch_log_sum_exp(score_t)  # [B, 1, C] -> [B, C, C]
            score = score_t * mask_t + score * (1 - mask_t)
        score = batch_log_sum_exp(score + self.transitions[self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]])
        return score  # partition function

    def _batch_score_sentence(self, feats, tags, mask):
        assert mask is not None
        score = torch.Tensor(feats.size(0)).fill_(0.)
        if feats.is_cuda:
            score = score.cuda()
        feats = feats.unsqueeze(3)
        mask = mask.float()
        trans = self.transitions.unsqueeze(2)
        add_start_tags = torch.empty(tags.size(0), 1).fill_(self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]).type_as(tags)
        tags = torch.cat([add_start_tags, tags], dim=-1)
        for t in range(feats.size(1)):  # recursion through the sequence
            mask_t = mask[:, t]
            emit_t = torch.cat([h[t, y[t + 1]] for h, y in zip(feats, tags)])
            trans_t = torch.cat([trans[y[t + 1], y[t]] for y in tags])
            score += (emit_t + trans_t) * mask_t
        last_tag = tags.gather(1, mask.sum(1).long().unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
        score += self.transitions[self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG], last_tag]
        return score

    def _batch_viterbi_decode(self, feats, mask):
        # initialize backpointers and viterbi variables in log space
        bptr = torch.LongTensor()
        score = torch.Tensor(feats.size(0), self.tagset_size).fill_(-10000.)
        score[:, self.tag_to_ix[START_TAG]] = 0.
        if feats.is_cuda:
            score = score.cuda()
            bptr = bptr.cuda()
        mask = mask.float()
        for t in range(feats.size(1)):  # recursion through the sequence
            mask_t = mask[:, t].unsqueeze(1)
            score_t = score.unsqueeze(1) + self.transitions  # [B, 1, C] -> [B, C, C]
            score_t, bptr_t = score_t.max(2)  # best previous scores and tags
            score_t += feats[:, t]  # plus emission scores
            bptr = torch.cat((bptr, bptr_t.unsqueeze(1)), 1)
            score = score_t * mask_t + score * (1 - mask_t)
        score += self.transitions[self.tag_to_ix[STOP_TAG]]
        best_score, best_tag = torch.max(score, 1)

        # back-tracking
        bptr = bptr.tolist()
        best_path = [[i] for i in best_tag.tolist()]
        for b in range(feats.size(0)):
            x = best_tag[b]  # best tag
            y = int(mask[b].sum().item())  # no. of non-pad tokens
            for bptr_t in reversed(bptr[b]):
                x = bptr_t[x]
                best_path[b].append(x)
            best_path[b].pop()
            best_path[b].reverse()

        best_path = torch.LongTensor(best_path)
        if feats.is_cuda:
            best_path = best_path.cuda()
        return best_path

    def _get_bert_features(self, input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask):
        sequence_output, _ = self.bert(input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask, output_all_encoded_layers=False)
        sequence_output = self.dropout(sequence_output)
        bert_feats = self.classifier(sequence_output)
        return bert_feats

    def forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=None, labels=None):
        bert_feats = self._get_bert_features(input_ids, token_type_ids, attention_mask)
        if labels is not None:
            forward_score = self._batch_forward_alg(bert_feats, attention_mask)
            gold_score = self._batch_score_sentence(bert_feats, labels, attention_mask)
            return (forward_score - gold_score).mean()
        else:
            tag_seq = self._batch_viterbi_decode(bert_feats, attention_mask)
            return tag_seq
```